# Vanderlee\Syllable as CodeIgniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I use this [phpSyllable](https://github.com/vanderlee/phpSyllable) project in CodeIgniter as a library? so that I can use it like

```
$this->load->library('Syllable');
$syllable = new Syllable('en-us');
echo $syllable->hyphenateText('Provide a plethora of paragraphs');
```

I can't load this library as the main class is in subfolder /src/.